# How to achieve Port Forwarding on OpenWrt routers?

Tags: port-forwarding, openwrt, ddns

I am trying to set up a qBittorent Web UI on my home computer that will be available to me everywhere through Dynamic DNS. I have read the relevant posts here but am still hitting a wall.

This is my setup : 
qBittorent 3.1.12 running on Linux Mint 17.1
I am using duckdns.org for DDNS through their Linux GUI 
My router is running on OpenWrt Chaos Calmer r45545.

[image: 1]

What I have done so far:
Enabled UPnP on the router and the redirects show up on the main page.

The duckdns log gives "OK" so I understand that everything should be working at DDNS provider's end.

On my computer, logging in with my local ip:port number (192.168.2.200:58080) successfully brings up the Web UI of qBittorent.

Trying the 'domain_name'.duckdns.org:58080 given an "Unable to connect" error.

Additionally, trying only 'domain_name'.duckdns.org gives a "Forbidden :
Rejected request from RFC1918 IP to public server address" error message.

Even more confusing for me is that the port checking tool 'canyouseeme' is able to "see" the port.

[image: 2]

I have installed 'gufw' and disabled the firewall on my PC.
I am clueless. I have tried various permutations and combinations but I know that there is something, some small checkbox or entry that I have missed and it probably lies with the router.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Port forwarding is achieved through the Network > Firewall menu.

For the error message:

```
Forbidden : Rejected request from RFC1918 IP to public server address
```

In the file `/etc/config/uhttpd`, you need to disable rfc1918_filter:

```
config uhttpd 'main'
        option rfc1918_filter '0'
```

The restart the http server:

```
/etc/init.d/uhttpd restart
```

This will let you access your router using it's public IP address from your LAN.

Comment: Is this a safe filter to disable? https://tools.kali.org/sniffingspoofing/rebind